# Yahoo ouath contacts using curl php broken broken

Tags: curl, oauth, contacts, yahoo, yql

OK, so I've been wasting about 4 hours now.. it should be simple, 125 characters or so, 2 to 4 lines in total. To end up fetching an array with Yahoo contacts.

I manage to successfully log in the user using simpleauth.php sample code provided with the latest sdk Yahoo offers. Now once the user is logged in I would need to run YQL:

This is a yql query:

```
select * from social.contacts where guid=me;
```

It should return all contacts, ok, can't get this to work as it seems there is more to add to the following code for yql to work:

```
$yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql";  

$yql_query = "select * from social.contacts where guid=me";  

$yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query); 
$yql_query_url .= "&format=json";

$curlParams = array (
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 0,
  CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE => false,
);

  $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlParams);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $yql_query_url);

 $content = curl_exec ( $ch );  
 print_r($content);
```

I don't get the contacts of course, instead I get:

```
 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-YQL-Host: engine2.yql.sp2.yahoo.com
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_PARAMETER_ABSENT_ERROR", realm="yahooapis.com"
```

And it's driving me crazy as it should work somehow out of the box, is meant for people to use without much problem - not 4 hours of research, editing and reading to determine it just won't work in a simple way. As opposed to google and microsoft contacts which I already managed to work.

It seems somehow I should add my

```
$client->setClientId('client_id');
$client->setClientSecret('client_secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('redirect_uri');
$client->setDeveloperKey('developer_key');
```

To the curl but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: have a look at this: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html Did you fix it already?

Comment: the problem is the documentation provides examples for the old yahoo api / sdk, the yql example I can't get it to work with `$two_legged_app = new YahooApplication(API_KEY,SHARED_SECRET);  ` because YahooApplication class doesn't exist anymore with the latest SDK, don't know it's equivalent.

Comment: Hi @Ibennet , Please share solution if you got any :|